# Can iOS Web Apps receive Apple Push notifications?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to evaluate whether to implement my application as a Web App or native app and was wondering if its possible to a web app to receive Apple Push notifications?
I suspect not but want to confirm so.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must use the SDK, the best way to achieve this would be to have a wrapper app for your web app.